# Is it good to keep multi-valued attributes in a table existing in a 24/7 running service?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, database-design

I am working on a project where I am using a table with a multi-valued attribute having 5-10 values. Is it good to keep multivalued attributes or should I normalize it into normal forms ?
But I think that it unnecessarily increases the no of rows.If we have 10 multi values for an attribute then each row or tuple will be replaced with new 10 rows which might increase the query running time.

Can anyone give suggestions on this?

Comment: See the `SET` datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first normal form requests that each attribute be atomic.

I would say that the answer to this question hinges on the “atomic”: it is too narrow to define it as “indivisible”, because then no string would be atomic, as it can be split into letters.

I prefer to define it as “a single unit as far as the database is concerned”. So if this array (or whatever it is) is stored and retrieved in its entirety by the application, and its elements are never accessed inside the database, it is atomic in this sense, and there is nothing wrong with the design.

If, however, you plan to use elements of that attribute in `WHERE` conditions, if you want to modify individual elements with `UPDATE` statements or (worst of all) if you want the elements to satisfy constraints or refer to other tables, your design is almost certainly wrong. Experience shows that normalization leads to simpler and faster queries in that case.

Don't try to get away with few large table rows. Databases are optimized for dealing with many small table rows.